# How to create a visual graph config in workbench mode

Tags: config, graphdb

This is my example.ttl:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com#> .

:NewYork a :City .
:London a :City .

:bob a :Person, :Man;
    :name "Bob";
    :bornIn :London.

:susan a :Person, :Woman;
    :name "Susan";
    :bornIn :NewYork.

:jane a :Person, :Woman;
    :name "Jane".

<<:bob :meet :susan>> :venue :NewYork; 
             :date "2020-10-12" .

<<:jane :told  :susan>> :about <<:bob :love :susan>>;
                              :date "2021-06-15" .
```

I import it into GraphDB, and Create visual graph config : I choose "Start with graph query results", I want get all nodes and edges in the graph, but I still don't know how to set the Graph expansion, Node basics and Edge basics.
Would anyone show me how to do it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Graph doesn't support RDF*, but you could expand all nodes by creating a construct query, using Standard Reification.
Go to Create graph config -> Start with graph query results and write following construct query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix : <http://example.com#>
CONSTRUCT {
    ?s a ?o;
       a ?o1;
       :name ?name;
       :bornIn ?cityBorn.
    :meeting rdf:subject ?pers1;
             rdf:predicate :meet;
             rdf:object ?pers2;
             :venue ?city.
    :gossip rdf:subject ?pers5;
            rdf:predicate :love;
            rdf:object ?pers6.
    :story rdf:subject ?pers3;
           rdf:predicate :told;
           rdf:object ?pers4.
    :story :about :gossip;
           :date ?date .
} WHERE {
    ?s a ?o;
       a ?o1;
       :name ?name.
    <<?pers1 :meet ?pers2>> :venue ?city.
    <<?pers3 :told  ?pers4>> :about <<?pers5 :love ?pers6>>;
                                             :date ?date .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?s :bornIn ?cityBorn.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konstantin.  It's nice to hear that the new version of GraphDB will support visualization of RDF *.